# HTML email css stripped after replacing text

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a html template that works when it is as is and sent to my Gmail. The css works and the positioning of elements is fine.

However, I when I load it into my application and do a replace string of certain text and resend it from my application, I noticed that in Gmail, not only is the css gone but all positioning is messed up.

This is my html email as is without replacing the text:

http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=00874388724644178645

This is how I load the html and replace the text:

```
HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
document.Load(@message.Location);
content = document.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
content = content.Replace("##" + innerItem + "##", line);
var eContent = new HtmlString(content);
```

I then proceed to sent the eContent string to my email via another function.

This is my html email after I replaced the text:

http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=03908737686605061545

I am unsure of how else I can handle this email template properly.

I'm using the HTML Agility Pack to read the document in also.

EDIT:

The replaced email works with other email providers like the CPanel one but not Gmail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might happen if you have any character Gmail doesn't support in styles (may it be inline or in  tags). This can include characters like =,*,/,$,%,`, &, @, ^, {, }, [, ], (, ), ?, |, <, > [more about that](https://github.com/hteumeuleu/email-bugs/issues/19). Feel free to post your code for further help.

Comment: I've posted the before and after code in my question. You can download those files.

Comment: @JianYA, sorry i cant access to that links. also, check link provided.

Comment: Sorry, the link works for me? Its a public filesharing site. do you have any other option to upload my files?

Comment: check this link, it might resole your mistery: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail)

Comment: I'm using MailKit in .net core to send.